# What does 'y.values == 0,1' evaluate to, y being a pandas series of 0s and 1s?

Tags: python, pandas

`y.values` is a pandas series and each of its elements is either 1 or zero.

My question is on what logic does `y.values == 0,1` evaluate to True or False?

I am trying to plot a decision boundary of a logistic regression model and the code that I am using:

```
def plot_mushroom_boundary(X, y, fitted_model):

    plt.figure(figsize=(9.8,5), dpi=100)

    for i, plot_type in enumerate(['Decision Boundary', 'Decision Probabilities']):
        plt.subplot(1,2,i+1)

        mesh_step_size = 0.01  # step size in the mesh
        x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .1, X[:, 0].max() + .1
        y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .1, X[:, 1].max() + .1
        xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, mesh_step_size), np.arange(y_min, y_max, mesh_step_size))
        if i == 0:
            Z = fitted_model.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
        else:
            try:
                Z = fitted_model.predict_proba(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])[:,1]
            except:
                plt.text(0.4, 0.5, 'Probabilities Unavailable', horizontalalignment='center',
                 verticalalignment='center', transform = plt.gca().transAxes, fontsize=12)
                plt.axis('off')
                break
        Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
        plt.scatter(X[y.values==0,0], X[y.values==0,1], alpha=0.4, label='Edible', s=5)
        plt.scatter(X[y.values==1,0], X[y.values==1,1], alpha=0.4, label='Posionous', s=5)
        plt.imshow(Z, interpolation='nearest', cmap='RdYlBu_r', alpha=0.15, 
               extent=(x_min, x_max, y_min, y_max), origin='lower')
        plt.title(plot_type + '\n' + 
              str(fitted_model).split('(')[0]+ ' Test Accuracy: ' + 
str(np.round(fitted_model.score(X, y), 5)))
        plt.gca().set_aspect('equal');
    
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.9, bottom=0.08, wspace=0.02)
```

Comment: "on what logic does y.values == 0,1 evaluate to True or False?" - It doesn't.

Comment: @superbrain  It does. Try running the code. y is a pandas series and contains 1s and 0s

Comment: No it doesn't. `y.values == 0,1` is a tuple. A tuple is no bool.

Comment: @superbrain My bad!! Yes its a tuple of  ([ Trues , Falses ], 1)

Comment: @sbhhdp  The expression only makes sense when used as indexing.  So `[y.values == 0,1 ]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `X` is a 2d array, and `y` a pandas Series, then

```
y.values`    # 1d array
y.values==0    # boolean 1d array, True where y.values is 0
```

Then this expression:

```
X[y.values==0, 0]
```

makes sense as doing boolean indexing of the first dimension of `X`, and 0 scalar indexing of columns.  I.e. the first column of `X` where `y` is 0.